Switching to node 18.18.0 using NVM, but Next complain on using different version of node (20.3.1) when starting new project
as the title mentioned, I am currently using node 18.18.0 for compatibility with next.js dependencies, i uninstalled every node version possible, and only kept one, yet on starting a new next project using this command:
npx create-next-app@14.2.17
and i get the following:

here is a verification of node version:


I found it, when using Everything, this version was in cache, so i deleted it.


It's probably because the npm-chache folder is registered in your environment variables settings that is not used by nvm.
